# What should a server-side script contain in order for file_get_contents() to work on the client side?

Tags: php

For the first time ever I've tried to use file_get_contents() in a file (index.php):

```
echo $globalIP=file_get_contents("tools.php");
```

The contents of tools.php, for the time being, is as follows:

```
<?php
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo $ip;
?>
```

but when I run index.php it doesn't display anything at all.

Peculiarly, all info on the Internet about file_get_contents() pertains to the client side rendering, and not about what the server-side script should contain. I also experimented with stream_context_create() in tools.php to no avail.

By the way, the idea is to replace the URL in

```
$globalIP=file_get_contents("http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com");
```

with my own script. Whatismyipaddress returns a string containing the IP, nothing else, which is what I am looking for.

Comment: `file_get_contents()` gets the contents of the file, it doesn't execute it

Comment: As @brombeer has mentioned `file_get_contents()` gets the contents not executes it, you want to `include`  the file instead, i suggest thinking if this is the best method for what yuo want to achieve though.

Comment: Thanks people! But if we neglect the purpose and concentrate on the programming issue on the server side, what should tools.php contain? I mean what do you think whatismyipaddress may have used to achieve this? As you see $globalIP=file_get_contents() works perfectly when the argument is their bot site's index file.

Comment: Yes it will be because you are grabbing the page after the serverside code has been ran and outputed to the page, Like I mentioned in my previous comment if you `include` the file it will run and output the result the serverside code in `tools.php`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was much more straightforward:

If a relative link is used, the php code of the actual file is displayed: `file_get_contents("tools.php")`!!!!

In order for it to work a full URL is needed, in my case:

`file_get_contents("http://localhost/tools.php");`